# How do I punctuate this sentence? A stamp cost three cents a gallon of gas twenty

Tags: punctuation, commas, semicolons

Do I use a semicolon or a comma? I do not want to add a conjunction or replace the missing "cost" after gas. Both are intentionally removed.

Comment: Semi-colon. You'll also want a period at the end of the sentence.

Comment: It also works fine as two sentences. `A stamp cost three cents. A gallon of gas, twenty.` The second sentence is an ellipsis, just like if you're asked "What would you like to buy?" and you say `A gallon of gas.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A stamp cost three cents; a gallon of gas, twenty.

Comment: The point is (as demonstrated here and in Reg's answer), that there are two breaks of contrasting severity. There are different ways of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

> A stamp cost three cents, a gallon of gas — twenty.